# Average Salesforce Certification case response time?

Tags: certification, support

Is there anyone to help me out please, I had taken the exam on 16 th of sep, 2014 and in between my exam was paused. **I have opened up a case with salesforce certification and still there's no response. How much time do they generally take to respond?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling 0016026594665, explain your case. I had the similar issue (Lost Internet connection), they were pretty supportive and rescheduled my exam. This was when I called them up immediately.

One of my colleague had a similar issue and raised a case, he got a response in about a weeks time.

My suggestion try both routes.